# How to make shapes not overlap in python turtle?

Tags: python, random, numbers, turtle-graphics

What technique should I use to make the numbers from the second picture not overlap as those in the first picture?
The positions of the numbers should be random.

[what I should have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OncHU.png)
[what I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlCjF.png)

Comment: you would have to remeber which places (squares) on screen are occupied and check if squares in next number will use them.

Comment: should i do it with set maybe? or is there any other quicker way?

Comment: your screen is like chessboard with squares - you could use `set()` to rember which suqares are occupied. And when you wan to put number then you would have to create `set()` with information which squares it would use on board - and then you can check if this set in set of already occupied squares.